# How to get record by Date in my case using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables `ProductLog` and `Product`

**ProductLog**

```
ProductID    TransDate    RegNo
--------------------------------
15           2022-03-05    4
15           2022-03-08    1
15           2022-03-10    3
```

**Product**

```
Date          ProductID
-----------------------
2022-03-01    15
2022-03-02    15
2022-03-03    15
2022-03-04    15
2022-03-05    15
2022-03-06    15
2022-03-07    15
2022-03-08    15
2022-03-09    15
2022-03-10    15
2022-03-11    15
2022-03-12    15
```

The select statement `RegNo` value to be `ProductLog.RegNo` , which is  `Product.Date <= ProductLog.TransDate`

I want to get a result like below
**Expected Output**

```
Date          ProductID   RegNo
-------------------------------
2022-03-01    15          4
2022-03-02    15          4
2022-03-03    15          4
2022-03-04    15          4
2022-03-05    15          4
2022-03-06    15          1
2022-03-07    15          1
2022-03-08    15          1
2022-03-09    15          3
2022-03-10    15          3
2022-03-11    15          0
2022-03-12    15          0
```

I tried by ranking order Date by ASC, and where rank =1, it set all to lowest date value. (I understand it is not a correct approach.)

what is the correct way to approach this?

Comment: @RF1991 I already have given the field names and values of the table. May I know what you need more.

Comment: more Explanation for your fields and what you want

Comment: @RF1991 can you check now

Comment: select  b.Date,b.ProductID,iif(RegNo is null ,0,RegNo) from  Product b
full join ProductLog  a
on a.ProductID=b.ProductID and b.Date<=a.TransDate

Comment: Is this what you want??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `APPLY` to find the `RegNo`

```
select p.Date, p.ProductID, RegNo = coalesce(l.RegNo, 0)
from   Product p
       outer apply
       (
           select top 1 l.RegNo
           from   ProductLog l
           where  l.ProductID = p.ProductID
           and    l.TransDate >= p.[Date]
           order by l.TransDate
       ) l
```

Comment: now I learned how outer apply works, the right table will calculate for each row based on left table. thanks

Answer (score 1):

use join as follows:

```
select 
  b.Date, 
  b.ProductID, 
  iif(RegNo is null, 0, RegNo) 
from 
  Product b 
  full join ProductLog a on a.ProductID = b.ProductID 
  and b.Date <= a.TransDate
```